# Building a userModel in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm currently experiencing a problem with my app. I store user data in Firebase and when the user ir using the app, and some of the details change in the user model, the user gets redirected to the Root view of the app. I tried creating an observable object, but i think that i didn't do it that well.

Currently, my setup of fetching users looks like this:

```
func fetchUsers(){
    ref.child("users").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]  else { return}
            var user = UserData()
            
            user.email = (dictionary["email"] as! String)
            user.name = (dictionary["name"] as! String)
            user.firstname = (dictionary["firstname"] as! String)
            user.lastname = (dictionary["lastname"] as! String)
            user.type = (dictionary["type"] as! String)
            user.uid = (dictionary["uid"] as! String)
            user.profileImageUrl = (dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as! String)
            user.id = snapshot.key
            user.fcmToken2 = (dictionary["fcmToken"] as! String)
            
            self.users.append(user)
            
        }
}
```

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var session : SessionStore
@State var userState = UserData()
@State private var functionResult = false

func getUser(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        session.listen()
        session.getUserFromUID { (fetcheduser) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.functionResult.toggle()
                self.userState = fetcheduser
                print("Auth State Changed")
                print(functionResult)
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        if (session.session != nil) {
    
            if(functionResult == true){
                MainView(user: userState)
            }
            
            else {
                DelayedLaunchScreen(user: userState)
            }
            
        }
        
        else{
            HomeView()
        }
    }.onAppear{
        getUser()
    }
}
}
```

MainView:

```
 UIKitTabView {
        CandidateListView().tab(title: "Kandidatai", image: "person.2")
        ChatsView(session: self.session).tab(title: "Žinutės", image: "message")
        ChatsHomeView(session: self.session, user: self.user).environmentObject(session).tab(title: "Darbo skelbimai", image: "newspaper")
        ProfileMenuView(session: self.session, user: self.user).tab(title: "Paskywra", image: "person")
        //CreateJobView(user: session.getUserFrom(uid: session.uid), session: self.session).tab(title: "Paskywra", image: "person")
    }
```

I'm guessing the problem is, that in the ContentView i have a function to fetch the user data and delay it with a fake launch screen. I dont really understand, why after a change in database the user gets popped to the root view. Is this because the user is being defined in the ContentView? Is there any other way to do this without causeing the problem? Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you edit this to include a [mre]? I can replace the Firebase part myself with something that returns sample data asynchronously or you could, but more importantly, it's necessary to see how the parts fit together to see what's causing the view to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is in how you structured the `if` that is depending on the `functionResult` bool:

```swift
if (functionResult == true) {
   MainView(user: userState)
} else {
   DelayedLaunchScreen(user: userState)
}
```

In your `session.getUserFromUID` you are toggling this state property that subsequently invalidates the `ContentView` that redraws the `MainView` if true or the `DelayedLaunchScreen`.

Basically every time the function is invoked (or fired if it's a listener) you are destroying what was rendered before. This might explain why it seems you are being popped out in the navigation stack.

You should be able to solve the problem by removing the `functionResult` property or by just using it once.

If this doesn't solve the issue, there must be something to do in the `MainView` and in how the `userState` is used to draw the views or maybe in that `if session.session` (maybe you can add more code to your question).

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the comment, for now, using the functionResult = true, and not .toggle() the view doesn't pop back to the MainView, but the content in the ProfileView is not updated until the app is restarted. Any ideas how to fix that? Thanks!